# Where to get an Ubuntu image for OpenStack running on XenServer

Tags: ubuntu, xen, openstack, para-virtualization

So...

I installed XenServer 6.2. I installed OpenStack via DevStack (https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack/blob/master/tools/xen/README.md). It successfully configured the OpenStack dashboard. I can launch new CirrOS instances.

But I have absolutely no idea how to fetch an Ubuntu PV image to use with it, and most of the tutorials I find out there seem outdated. I also tried to download cloud.ubuntu but I have no idea what format should I specify for the tar.gz file (and I somehow suspect it's not a PV image).

Help?

Answer (score 0):

I made a post [here](https://plus.google.com/112168893448921176598/posts/ECKYMuofXFv) .  It tells you how to convert any other image to an appropriate format for xenserver to accept.  It also links to the original sources.  In a nutshell, xenserver itself needs a special format.

Comment: Please copy (and if needed, edit accordingly) the post you link to. What happens if the link will go broken? It is preferred that all the answer will be hosted on this site.